# SharePoint Online back-end for a mobile application, with guest users

Tags: api, sharepoint, external

I would like to use SharePoint Online as a back-end for a new mobile application.

**Need**

- Mobile application with a lot of users, SharePoint back-end. Without needing to have a licence for each user.

**Setup idea**

- SharePoint Online with 5 licenced users, that can access SharePoint itself
- Mobile application with <10.000 users, all included in SharePoint/AD as guest users.
- The mobile application gets/posts everything via SharePoint API's & O365 Graph API's

**Fears**

- Can guest users get access via SharePoint API's & O365 Graph
- Limitation on # of guest users?
- API call limitation/throtteling (how soon? / Can this be bought off?)

Are these fears actually an issue? And if so, can you help me to bypass my fears :) ?

Thanks in advance.
Wouter

---

**Research done:**

- Limitation of calls/user

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/capacity-planning-and-load-testing-sharepoint-online-c932bd9b-fb9a-47ab-a330-6979d03688c0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online

- Can guests users use API's?

https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/08/10/sharepoint-online-external-user-access-error-user-not-in-directory/